# SFDX: Push Source to Default Scratch Org failed to run (no stated errors just exit code 1)

Tags: salesforcedx

When pushing code with no visible error I receive the message below:

```
15:43:39.203 sfdx force:source:push --json --loglevel fatal
15:43:43.134 sfdx force:source:push --json --loglevel fatal ended with exit code 1
```

I deleted the lwc I was currently working on and I still get the following message. I can not seem to figure out what is going on because there is no error message but `"ended with exit code 1"`

Answer (score 2):

You can go to Setup -> Deployment Status and check if there is any other information about the error you are facing. Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am using VScode and can not find these settings. Any other ideas?

Comment: You will find it in the Salesforce org you are deploying, sandbox, scratch org or whatever you are using. Not in VScode.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this issue with deploy on save enabled, I suppose it's from the `--json` flag which returns the errors in JSON except it's not going anywhere.

The easiest way I was able to see the issues is just manually typing `sfdx force:source:push` in the terminal.  That should give you details about the failures right there in your VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it happen when I've got some mistake in an `import {} from library;` statement, for example: `import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';`

Here if we change it to `platformShowTostEvent (basically, a spelling mistake) then it happens.